# input validation against DB in Spring+hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, passwords

Its spring MVC app with Hibernate.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean save(User user) {

        return userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {

        userDao.update(user);

        // return this.userDao.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findById(int id) {

        return this.userDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listPersons() {

        return this.userDao.listPersons();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User deleteUser(int id) {

        return userDao.deleteUser(id);
    }

    public boolean validateUser(int id) {

        List<User> list= (List<User>) findById(id); 


        return false;   


    }

    public User validateUser(User user) {   

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        String query = "select u.name, u.password from User as u where u.name='"+ user.getName() + "' and u.password='"
                + user.getPassword() + "'";

        session.createQuery(query);       

        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) session.createQuery (query);

            try {
                if (rs.next()){

                    return user;
                } else
                    return user;
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return user;

        }
}
My UserServiceImpl class has a method to validate the user input[ password and userID];
```

User logs in to a login.jsp page filling out this form:

```
<body>

    Welcome back!

    <br> Only Registered user can log in...
    <br>
    <br>
    <form:form action="admin" modelAttribute="user" method="POST">
        <table border="1">

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userId">Your Id:- </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Password:- </form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="role">Select Log in role as a:- </form:label></td>
                <td><form:select path="role">
                        <form:option value="NONE" lable="---SELECT---">Please Select</form:option>
                        <form:options items="${roles}" />
                    </form:select></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

The form goes to contrroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String LoggedUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        // get the role, id and pw value from jsp
        String role = user.getRole();
        String loadedPW = user.getPassword();
        String loadedUId = user.getUserId();
        // want to check password and userId here again Db
        //loadedPW.

      //directing to admin page and gen page
    if (role.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin") || role.equalsIgnoreCase("Principal")) {
            return "adminPage";         
        } else
            return "genPage";
    }
```

My User object is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")/*    
    @NotNull(message="Please select a password")
    @Length(min=5, max=10, message="Password should be between 5 - 10 charactes")*/ 
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
    private String department;
    @Column(name = "RID")
    private int rid;    
    public int getRid() {
        return rid;
    }
    public void setRid(int rid) {
        this.rid = rid;
    }   
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })

    /*@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)*/
    public Roles roles;

    public Roles getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Roles roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    // no arg constructor
    public User() {
//getters and setters ........
    }
```

How can I validate the password and userID inputs on login.jsp against my User table?
Do I have to use JDBC Resultset or there is some other better way to do validate the user inputs? I am using Hibernate 4.3x with Spring MVC 4.x .

Answer (score 1):

> How can I validate the password and userID inputs on login.jsp against
>   my User table?

You can use `spring-security` module, which is very powerful for authenticating & authorizing the user requests (like in your web application) and you can find an example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

`spring-security` module provides various methods to configure the user details like inmemory, database, LDAP, etc.., but for your case you need to go for JDBC authentication using `(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.jdbcAuthentication())`.

The approach is you need to provide a configuration class by overriding methods `configAuthentication`() and `configure`() methods of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

> Do I have to use JDBC Resultset or there is some other better way to
>   do validate the user inputs?

No, you don't need to handle JDBC `Resultset` directly, rather in `spring-security`, you just need to provide the `datasource` (database access details) and `sql` query like `select username,password from users where username=?`.

You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html) for configuring JDBC authentication.

Comment: Spring security will not go to remote database for password validation rather  stored username/password combination in configuration file itself. But i want it to act  like  more real time applications, where some user service fetching data from remote database.

Comment: No, you need to configure the remote database hostname, port, dbname, userid, pwd as part of datasource properties, that's it